# How can I link a static library to a cpp file?

Tags: object, compilation, static-libraries

I have a static library called X.a and a cpp file called Y.cpp. Y.cpp conatins the main function and uses the functions in X.a. How can I compile Y.cpp such that X.a is included and finally make a Z.a which also includes Y.o ?

Comment: Why would you make a static library from an object file that contains `main()`?

Comment: BTW, `g++ -c -Wall -o Y.o Y.cpp` then `ar -x X.a` then `ar -cvs Z.a *.o`

Comment: But, won't the first step throw an error as I would be using the functions defined in X.a ?

Comment: Compilation is not linkage, and declarations are not definitions.

Comment: I will tell you my exact problem. I have a libcx3d.a which contains my VrmlParser class and other classes which are used by VrmlParser. I have a main.cpp which does this :

`VrmlParser vp = new VrmlParser();
 double **VOB = vp.getVOB();`

 When I compile using g++ main.cpp -o main -L. -lcx3d, I get the  following errors :

 'VrmlParser' was not declared in this scope.
 expected ';' before vp.
 'vp' was not declared in this scope.

 What should I do ?